# Approach to solving the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was working on a problem when I encountered the infinite series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{n}x^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} = 2x^{\frac{1}{2}}+4x^{\frac{1}{4}}+8x^{\frac{1}{8}}+16x^{\frac{1}{16}}...$$
I've played around with it a bit but I am not sure how to approach this kind of infinite series. I don't know if there are common techniques to find a closed form for this type of infinite series(where the power of x itself is a geometric series), I only know basic geometric series and power series.

Thanks!

Comment: This does not converge for any non-zero $x$ (except when you have a $2$-adic topology).

Comment: Oh wow ya of course - I'm not sure how I missed that - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For the lower bounds, you can compare the series to either of the two integrals (the former for $x>1$,  the latte for $0<x<1$:
$$
\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{\frac{1}{x}} dx\\
\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{1}{x}}dx
$$
both of which diverge